# Нюанс c/c++ про возвращаемое значение функции

Tags: c++, c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему этот код не вызывает ошибку? Если правильно понимаю даже не смотря на то, что функция возвращает значение, оно просто будет отброшено,верно?

Comment: Да, оно будет отброшено. Вызывающий код не обязан обрабатывать возвращаемое функцией значение, если она не помечена атрибутом `[[nodiscard]]` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 2):

Возвращаемое значение имеет тип временного, а временное значение не обязательно должно быть связано с чем-нибудь.
Разрешается даже использовать такие записи :

```
  13 ; // просто число
  2+2 ; // 4 - временное число
  f(a); // просто результат вызова функции
  f ; // просто указатель
```

и эти временные значения просто игнорируются.

*В стандарте C23 , C++17 появилась запись `[[nodiscard]] int f(int){..}` для вывода предупреждений, что возвращаемое значение не используется.*